# Expanding a structure while keeping it a model of theory

Tags: first-order-logic

Just so you know, this is a homework-related question.

Let $L=\{0,f\}$ a language, and denote $(f^M)^n(a)=f^M(f^M(...f^M(a))...)$

I must show that there exists a model $M$ that satisfies:

- for every $n\in\mathbb N$ there exists $a\in |M|$ s.t. if $k<n$ then $(f^M)^k(a)\neq 0^M$ and $(f^M)^n(a)=0^M$ .
- for every $a\in\mathbb N$ there exists $n\in \mathbb N$ s.t. $(f^M)^n(a)=0^M$

So I took $M$'s world to be the naturals (with zero) and defined:

$f^{M}(a)=\begin{cases}
\underline{0} & a=\underline{0}\\
a-\underline{1} & a>\underline{0}
\end{cases} $

So far so good.

Now I must show that there exists a model $M'$ of $T=Th(M)$, and $b\in M'$ s.t. for all $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $(f^{M'})^{n}(b)\neq0^{M'}$.
This is where I'm stuck.

I tried to let's say add $\infty$ to the world of some model $M'$ of $T$, and define $f^{M}(\infty)=\infty$, but how do I show it's still a model of $T$?

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new set of axioms.  Take a distinguished element $c$ and add $c \neq 0, c \neq f(0), c \neq f(f(0)) \dots$  Any finite set of them has a model, you just take $c$ large enough. So by compactness, the whole set has a model.

Comment: You mean I should look at $T\cup\{c\neq(f^{M})^{n}(0):n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}\}$, and that has a model?

Comment: That is correct.